Delta Lake (OSS) merge operation never finishes (or takes too long)
I am experimenting with Delta Lake as the primary storage solution for my tabular data, which is updated daily. I tried to mimic the basic use case - an existing target table is updated by the new data that can change existing data, i.e. upserts. I am using a MERGE INTO operation, where the target table is my Delta table and the table with updates is simply saved as a Parquet file.
My tables are special in the number of columns - there are up to 10000 columns, most of them are binary. One column contains an identifier of a row, represented as a string hash, which is used in the matching condition of the merge operation.
I am experimenting with a small main table having 5000 rows, which is 10 MB of one Parquet file on disk and the same table, but stored as a plain Parquet, which has several small 3.5 MB files.
My merge operation takes extremely long, probably stuck without any computation. What am I missing? I haven't tried partitioning, since the size of the whole table is just 10 MB. I expected this operation to be extremely fast even in the case of non-optimized tables.
I will appreciate your help, thank you!
UPD: added the code to reproduce the issue.
Spark version: 3.5.1.
Delta Lake (delta-spark) version: 3.1.0.
Instance: r5n.16xlarge
The only output that I get is
24/05/20 14:18:21 WARN DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size 1094.0 KiB 
24/05/20 14:18:21 WARN DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size 1097.6 KiB

Then the Spark session hangs and does nothing. The code does not finish.


import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from delta import *

def get_spark():
    builder = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName('SparkDelta') \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "32g") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", 
                "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.1.0,"
                "io.delta:delta-storage:3.1.0") \
    
    spark = builder.getOrCreate()

    return spark
    
    
spark = get_spark()

### GENERATE SOME FAKE DATA

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

num_rows = 5000
num_cols = 10000
array = np.random.rand(num_rows, num_cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df = df.reset_index()
df.to_csv('features.csv')


### DATA TO DELTA LAKE TABLE

df_spark = spark.read.format('csv').load('features.csv')
df_spark.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite").save('deltalake_features')

# Creating data to merge - just first 100 rows
df_slice = df.iloc[:100, 0:2]
df_slice.to_csv('features_slice_100.csv')

df_spark_slice = spark.read.format('csv').load('features_slice_100.csv')


### MERGE INTO code

target_delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'deltalake_features')
df_updates = df_spark_slice
df_target = target_delta_table.toDF()

(
    target_delta_table.alias('target')
    .merge(
        df_updates.alias('updates'),
        (
            (F.col('target._c1') == F.col('updates._c1'))
        )
    )
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set={
        '_c2': F.lit(42)
    })
    .execute()
)




how big is your compute cluster? what is your storage medium? please also share your code and table structure.

Doesn't matter which cluster I use - the it always takes eternity either on 64CPU 512GB RAM single node cluster or a real AWS EMR cluster of 4 executors running on r5n.xlarge instances (4CPU, 32 GB RAM).
The storage doesn't matter either - I observe the same behavior when tables are saved into S3 bucket or locally.
The code is standard from MERGE INTO example. I simply take one delta lake table and one parquet table and I want to merge them.

Feel free to add to your question to explain your code and table structure as this matters and could be the cause of your problem.

Did it, take a look.

In you sample code, driver mem set as 32g with master("local[4]") . In case of this, there is not enough memory for executor in node. How about reduce driver mem to 1~2g?( or submit to spark cluster, ex: standalone cluster .master("spark://{your spark cluster URI}") )
